# How to make custom URL in Symfony-2.3.12?

Tags: php, symfony-forms, symfony-2.3

I am getting problem in setting custom URL in Symfony-2.3.12. I am new to Symfony.
I am using Symfony-2.3.12 in fedora. I have set up application which I can call using the URL

```
http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/sample/hello
```

I want URL like this:

```
http://localhost/Symfony/sample/hello
```

I have read the routing documentation given in Symfony-2.3.12. But could not understand how to do this.
Please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are two default front controller in symfony 2. app.php for production environment and app_dev.php for development environment. All the request route with this front controller.

```
localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/sample/hello
```

means you are using development environment.

```
localhost/Symfony/web/sample/hello
```

means you are using production  environment.

You can add virtual host in httpd-vhosts.conf  to change

```
  http://localhost/Symfony/web/
```

path with your desire path.

Answer (score 1):

whether in dev mode or production having mod_rewrite enabled and the directory set to web in the vhost.conf or httpd.conf returns clean urls:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.yourSite.com.localhost
ServerAlias yourSite.com.localhost
ServerAdmin yourAdmin@localhost

DocumentRoot /var/www/vhost.d/siteFolder/web/
<Directory /var/www/vhost.d/siteFolder/web/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app_dev.php [QSA,L] ##or app.php for prod mode
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

see symfony doc for more info http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html